# Duplicate policy - are we wanting "good" duplicates?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/why-does-sh-say-not-found-when-its-definitely-there) that could be considered a duplicate. However, the wording of the question is very different and I think it can definitely aid people who are searching for such a problem. I believe this falls into the category of a good duplicate question; of the kind that [Jeff Atwood has mentioned before](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

However, two people have voted to close it. Should this question be closed or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike questions closed for other reasons, duplicates are not intended to be eventually deleted (except for egregious cases where they are *word for word identical*). The closed duplicate remains as search fodder.

A question should be closed as a duplicate as another if its answers are the same as the other question. In this case, the basic explanation is the same: your binary is compiled for a different loader. There is a difference in the details: the earlier question had an executable compiled for the wrong CPU architecture, while yours has an executable compiled for the wrong system library architecture. So there is perhaps some value in keeping different answers; it's a borderline case.

Answer (score 4):

I think your question is a "good" duplicate in that it comes at the problem from a different angle. However it is still a duplicate. *The answers are the same as for the other question*.

Having a question closed as a duplicate is not a bad thing. If your copy had identical wording or was otherwise a "bad" duplicate it might eventually get deleted. That's not the same thing as being closed.

Closing duplicates just helps ensure that all the possible relevant answers to a given problem are in one place. Duplicate questions can be good but there is litte sense in duplicate answers.*

The exception would be if the answers to your question were going to contain content uniquely tailored to your significantly different issue. In this case I think knowing the other answer is going to lean you and anybody else that lands on your question to be able to solve their problem. If for some reason you need help inside your unique context that the other question doesn't cover, feel free to request that it stay open. You might want to edit it with specific enough wording that it is clear how you are looking for a different answer.

<sub>* Note this is a point on which I don't 100% agree with Jeff.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Remember the close vote will result in the original question be linked to, so those who find the dupe won't be facing a dead-end. So yes, it should be closed if it is indeed a dupe, unless you believe the question (how it was asked) will lead to different answers.